# Listview to uiwebview?

Tags: ios, listview, ios5, uiwebview

I can create a list of 5 websites in a listview but how do I get it to do this..

On clicking one of the items in the list it should then take me to a uiwebview to display the URL within the app with a back button to the listview?

Is there an example or tutorial for this?

Thanks

**Attempt is as follows:** (sites don't appear in the table list - trying to make them appear and clickable to open internally in the app)

A tableview named "sites" has been added to a tab on my app.

*tabcontroller.m*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sites didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
            break;

        case 1:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com"]];
            break;

        case 2:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
            break; 

        case 3:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.yahoo.com"]];
            break;

        case 4:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.msn.com"]];
            break;               
    }

}
```

*tabcontroller.h*

```
@interface TabController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *sites;

}
```

Comment: Thsi will not load in the webview but opens in safari outside the application

Comment: Thanks Lithu T.V - going back to your example now

Answer (score 1):

Load webview with an url

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

1. Create 2 viewcontrollers
2. First  [populate a tableview showing urls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79239/iPhone-Programming-Tutorial-UITableView-Hello-Worl),
3. One the second VC add a UIWebview and create its IBoutlet
4. On did select tableview method push second viewcontroller ,pass the
   url
5. Use the above code in second view controller to load the webview
   with url

Comment: Thank you! Half of that flew over my head - is there a source example from going from a tableview with an array of url's?

Comment: Try it and and if you have some problem then add it in the question

Comment: added a link for the tutorial to populate the tableview

Answer (score 0):

I think , this way of approach is good for your situation.

Create 2 class files `1] UIViewController && 2] UITableViewController` .

Add the TableViewController to the UIViewController just like the slider from left to right or any with animations . TableViewController should be small , it should be good.

[image: TableViewController Acts Like Slider with UIviewController]

In the TableViewController , `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method pass the URL to the ViewController and make it like reload by using `PushNavigationController` ,

> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    contactUsController *CUC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactUs" ];
    [CUC setDetailItem:[ "URLLists" objectAtIndex:path.row]]; //set the Url to your VIEWCONTROLLER. // Just give Names for your URl in The table & match this name and assign Url n load WebView
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:CUC animated:YES];
```

in UIViewController just handle with UIWebView  according to the URL.